# Error en mi código de JApplet

Tags: java

Alguien  me puede ayudar estoy programando en vsc pero me salen error cuando trato de ejecutar mi JApplet

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.util.Random;
    
    import javax.swing.JApplet;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Applet extends JApplet
{
    int opcion;
    public void init() 
    {
        String entrada;
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        (
            "Estrciba 1 para dibujar lineas \n" + 
            "Escriba 2 para dibujar \n" + 
            "Escriva 3 para dibujar óvalos\n"
        );
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Random rand = new Random();
        float r = rand.nextFloat();
        float gr = (float)(rand.nextFloat()/2f + 0.5);
        float b = rand.nextFloat()/2f;
        Color randomColor = new Color(r, gr, b);

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)   
        switch (opcion)        
        {        
            case 1:
                g.drawLine(10, 10, 250, 10 + i * 10);
                break;
            case 2:
                g.drawRect(10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10);
                break;
            case 3:
                g.drawOval(10 + i * 10, 10 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10, 50 + i * 10);
                break;
            default:
                g.drawString("VALOR INCORRECTO", 25, 20 + i * 15);
        }
    }
}
```

y me salen estos errores

1. The type JApplet is deprecated since version 9
2. The serializable class Applet does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
3. The type JApplet is deprecated since version 9
4. The value of the local variable randomColor is not used

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Juraría que todo eso son advertencias, no son errores. Los applets están desaconsejados desde hace años, las clases serializables deben incluir un identificador para saber si ha cambiado su especificación y tienes una variable que no has usado, randomColor. Si no te deja compilar por lo del JApplet, puedes intentarlo con una versión de Java inferior.

Comment: Como comenta Ordago, los applets son obsoletos, puedes usar una versión menor a Java 9 ,pero lo aconsejable es dejar de usarlos, usa el WebView de JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

El error principal es el que indica que los Java Applets son obsoletos desde Java versión 9,

> The type JApplet is deprecated since version 9

**los Java Applets es una tecnología obsoleta que ya no debería usarse actualmente**.

**Como alternativa puedes usar [JavaFX y WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).**

Puedes revisar más información en el comunicado de Oracle donde indica en Enero 2016 que los Applets serán obsoletos en Java 9:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/migratingfromapplets-2872444.pdf
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdatev2020may-6548840.pdf

> Con los proveedores de navegadores modernos trabajando para restringir
> o reducir el soporte de complementos como Flash, Silverlight y Java en
> sus productos, desarrolladores de aplicaciones que se basan en la El
> complemento del navegador Java debe considerar opciones alternativas.
> Los desarrolladores de Java actualmente confían en los complementos
> del navegador debería considerar la posibilidad de migrar de Java
> Applets a Java sin complementos Tecnología Web Start.

> La compatibilidad con Java en los navegadores solo es posible mientras
> los proveedores de navegadores estén comprometido con el soporte de
> complementos basados ​​en estándares. A finales de 2015, muchos
> proveedores de navegadores había eliminado o anunciado plazos para la
> eliminación del complemento basado en estándares soporte, mientras que
> algunos están introduciendo API de extensión específicas del navegador
> propietarias. En consecuencia, Oracle planea desaprobar el complemento
> del navegador Java en JDK 9. La tecnología de complementos obsoleta se
> eliminará por completo de Oracle Java Development Kit (JDK) y Java
> Runtime Environment (JRE) en una futura versión de Java TBD. Las
> aplicaciones Java Web Start no dependen de un complemento de navegador
> y no se verán afectadas por estos cambios.

Con respecto a el mensaje:

> The serializable class Applet does not declare a static final
> serialVersionUID field of type long

Revisa la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) :

> El tiempo de ejecución de serialización asocia con cada clase
> serializable un número de versión, llamado serialVersionUID, que se
> usa durante la deserialización para verificar que el remitente y el
> receptor de un objeto serializado hayan cargado clases para ese objeto
> que sean compatibles con respecto a la serialización. Si el receptor
> ha cargado una clase para el objeto que tiene un serialVersionUID
> diferente al de la clase del remitente correspondiente, la
> deserialización resultará en una InvalidClassException. Una clase
> serializable puede declarar su propio serialVersionUID explícitamente
> declarando un campo llamado "serialVersionUID" que debe ser estático,
> final y de tipo long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

puedes usa la anotación @SuppressWarnings("serial") para que no se muestre este aviso.

Con respecto a el mensaje:

> The value of the local variable randomColor is not used

estas declarando la variable  `Color randomColor = new Color(r, gr, b);`, pero esta no es usada en tu código.